# The curvature tensor of a Kähler manifold in local coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Trying to understand the following calculation：

[image: please press here to see the calculation]

The key confusion for me is the fact that $\partial_{\bar j} g^{p \bar q} = g^{p \bar s} g^{r \bar q} \partial_{\bar j} g_{r \bar s} $(where $g^{i\bar j}$ is the (i,j)th entry of the inverse of the metric) . According to the notes, they get this formula due to the fact that $\delta A^{-1} = - A^{-1} \delta A A^{-1}$.

My understanding is that componentwisely $(\delta A^{-1})_{ij} = - (A^{-1})_{im} (\delta A)_{mn} (A^{-1})_{nj}$，so we should really get $\partial_{\bar j} g^{p \bar q} = g^{p \bar r} g^{s \bar q} \partial_{\bar j} g_{r \bar s} $ according to this formula.

In our case: $\partial_{\bar j} g^{p \bar q}$ is the pq-entry of the derivative of the inverse of metric. So according to the formula above it should be the product of:

- pr-entry($g^{p \bar r}$) $\times$ rs-entry($\partial_j g_{r \bar s}$) $\times$ sq-entry ($g^{s\bar q}$).(with summation over r and s).

So the formula in the notes really got me confused, and I have been thinking about this for a very long time since I am new to Riemannian geometry. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: No, $g^{i\bar j}$ is the $ij$-entry of the *inverse* of the metric.

Comment: Yes, and thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you dropped a negative sign in your discussion.  You have to be careful with barred and unbarred indices, so as to maintain the summation convention. Thus, you should rewrite your formula with barred and unbarred indices more carefully.  They also switched dummy summation variables at the end to add some confusion.
From $\partial_{\bar j}g^{p\bar q} = -g^{p\bar s}g^{r\bar q}\partial_j g_{r\bar s}$, we get
\begin{align*}
-g_{p\bar\ell}\partial_{\bar j}g^{p\bar q} &= g_{p\bar\ell}g^{p\bar s}g^{r\bar q}\partial_j g_{r\bar s} 
= \delta^{\bar s}_{\bar\ell}g^{r\bar q}\partial_j g_{r\bar s} \\ &= g^{r\bar q}\partial_j g_{r\bar\ell} = g^{p\bar q}\partial_j g_{p\bar\ell},
\end{align*}
as desired.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, let's quickly derive the formula for the derivative of the inverse. From
$$0 = D(\delta_i^j) =  D(h_{i\bar j}h^{k\bar j})$$
and the product rule, we get
$$0 = (Dh_{i\bar j})h^{k\bar j} + h_{i\bar j}(Dh^{k\bar j}),$$
so, multiplying by $h^{i\bar\ell}$ (and summing), we get
$$-h^{i\bar\ell}(Dh_{i\bar j})h^{k\bar j} = h^{i\bar\ell}h_{i\bar j}(Dh^{k\bar j}) = \delta^{\bar\ell}_{\bar j}(Dh^{k\bar j}) = Dh^{k\bar\ell},$$
as needed. Note that your "inconsistencies in matrix multiplication" occur throughout.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However my confusion is really with the equality $\partial_{\bar j} g^{p \bar q} = - g^{p \bar s} g^{r \bar q} \partial_{j} g_{r \bar s}$ since in my opinion it should rather be equal to $-g^{p \bar r} \partial_{j} g_{r \bar s} g^{s \bar q}$. Since my understanding is according to the corresponding formula for the derivative of the matrix: componentwisely $(\delta A^{-1})_{ij} = - (A^{-1})_{im} (\delta A)_{mn} (A^{-1})_{nj}$. I have updated my description to make it clearer.

Comment: I already told you that the formulas have to be modified in accordance with the summation convention in the complex case. Upper bar pairs with lower bar; you can't have it otherwise. Note that the inverse matrix condition must be $g_{i\bar j}g^{k\bar j} = \delta_i^k$, despite what you want to write. Complex geometry has its subtleties; this is one of them.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!! Can you maybe explain a little bit what is the reason for this? I cannot find any explanations elsewhere. My apologies if not understanding what you mean earlier but I really have been stuck on this for quite some time.

Comment: What book are you reading? .... This is something I had to come to terms with when I was working on my thesis over 40 years ago. The usual summation convention with upper and lower indices balancing does not work with hermitian metrics. To be invariant, one must pay attention to upper and lower pairings with bars or without bars; if you lower an index, then you can write $h_{i\bar j}h_{j\bar k}$ with the summation convention giving something well-defined.

Comment: I am really just reading some random notes I found online cause I am not in the area. Just want one final clarification before I stop bothering you. The claim that $g_{i \bar j} g^{k \bar j} = \delta_{ik}$ can be proved using normal coordinates where we choose $g_{i \bar j} = \delta_{ij}$, then we get the conculsion because $g_{i \bar j} g^{k \bar j}$ is invariantly defined.

Comment: @Chris No, that's the definition of the inverse!

Comment: But that is the component wise product of i th column of the metric inverse with the k th column of the metric itself, I do not see how will the definition of being inverse imply this being $\delta_{ik}$? For instance if we take the matrix $((1,i), (1,i))$ and its inverse is $((i/2, 1/2), (-i/2, 1/2))$, the componentwise product of the first column is not zero.  However I think we can prove the stated equality using normal coordinates and its invariance property.

Comment: Is it because $(g_{j \bar k})$ being inverse does not mean the matrix inverse?

Comment: Hermitian forms are not linear maps, and they transform by different rules when you change basis. So be careful thinking of everything with matrix multiplication (which corresponds to composition of linear maps). Indeed, raising the indices turns a tensor of type (2,0) into a tensor of type (0,2).

Comment: See my edit. I figured you would have worked it out for yourself, but in case not ....